# Inverse of "nearest neighbor" matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if this is standard terminology, so I will define what I mean here:

A **nearest neighbor matrix** is a matrix $M_{\vec{x}\vec{y}}$, whose indices $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in S\subset\mathbb{Z}^n$ are points on some finite $n$-dimensional lattice, with the condition that $|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|>1\implies M_{\vec{x}\vec{y}}=0.$ Here $|\vec{x}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$ is the standard Euclidean norm.

When $n=1$, this is a tridiagonal matrix. In this case, there is a nice formula for the inverse in terms of two sequences detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Inversion).

My question, is there *anything* that can be said about the more general $n>1$ case? Is there an analogous formula? I'm particularly interested in the $n=2$ case.

Comment: no takers? ok :(

Comment: In order to treat $n>1$ as a normal matrix, you are going to have to pick some indexing $\{x_k\}{k=1}^N = S$ of your lattice. Then you can use the $k$ as the matrix indices. "Tridiagonal" is lost, but the diagonal elements will always be $1$, the matrix will be symmetric, and all elements are either $1$ or $0$. The problem of inverting large matrices is well-studied, and there are many algorithms available.